# AS400 ( Limited capability and initial menu = signoff)

Tags: ibm-midrange

If a user has upltcp=No and intial menu=signoff, is the user considered a privileged user?

Comment: UPLTCP simply means that the user has access to the "green screen".  In some shops everyone has this access, so "privileged" or not depends on shop policy.  I'm not sure what it would mean to combine that with initial menu = SIGNOFF -- I'm a little fuzzy (it's been 10 years), but it seems to me that that would negate access to pretty much everything other than their initial program.

Comment: @HotLicks Hi thanks for the insight, can I ask, if a person is part of a group profile and that group profile is disabled, does that means all the users who are members of that group profile is disabled as well?

Comment: 1) What do you mean by 'privileged'?  Normally I would associate that word with a security officer.  Could you describe why this is important to know?  Are auditors asking for a list of privilege users?

Comment: 2) If a group profile is disabled, it means that someone cannot sign on with that profile.  People who are members of that group can still sign on.

Comment: Buck's question is a good one for clarification. Why are you asking? It's certainly possible that you have `privileged` user profiles that are all set for `upltcp=No and intial menu=signoff`, but that would be a part of your site's standards. It's not something that most sites would do. If we knew why you need to ask the question, a useful answer might be possible.

Comment: Hmm, auditors are asking. If upltcp=No and intial menu=signoff, then would that mean that user accounts can still have access to the command line and may change their initial programs, meaning that they can access production objects? Thanks~

Comment: If the DSPUSRPRF *outfile shows UPLTCP=*NO for a user, the user has the ability to run commands on a command line _for commands that the user has authority to_. That's separate from any ability to access "production objects" and in many cases completely unrelated. The UPLTCP=*NO attribute doesn't restrict command-line access except for menus or similar objects that test the attribute to see if a command-line should be presented for such users; most system menus do not check and shouldn't need to. You have to determine how your applications handle it.

Comment: Also, the attribute restricts the user's ability to change initial program/initial menu on a standard signon panel. (IMO, if you don't want users to change those, they shouldn't be shown on the panel.)

Comment: @user2338816 How do I know what commands that the user has authority to? Auditor is asking me to prove that even though the user has UPLTCP=*NO, it is not a risk.

Answer (score 0):

To review specific authorities a user has for commands, run:

```
DSPUSRPRF USRPRF( someuser ) TYPE(*CMDAUT)
```

The listed commands will be those for which the user has been granted authority. Other commands are also available if they're allowed for any limited capability user (e.g., SNDMSG).